# How Anderson-Darling test with Braun's method works in R?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, heavy-tailed, anderson-darling-test

I generally work with skewed and heavy-tailed lifetime distributions, so I need to check the goodness-of-fit of certain data to such distributions. After some exploration, I came to know that the AD test is preferable to the KS or CVM test in such cases as it can capture the deviations in the tail.

But the AD test also suffers when the parameters are estimated from the data. The `goftest` package in R offers a solution by Braun's method, but the details of the method are not given there.

After reading the [Paper](https://www.math.ku.dk/bibliotek/arkivet/preprints-fra-ims/1978/preprint_1978_-_no_8_braun__henry_-_a_simple_method_for_testing_goodness_of_fit_in_the_presence_of_nuisance_parameters.pdf) mentioned in the reference, I understood that the p-value is obtained through a resampling technique, but the complete technical concept is still not clear to me.

I've run the following code and got the following results:

```r
 testsamp=rnorm(100) #Generating random sample from standard normal
 ad.test(testsamp, "pnorm", mean=0, sd=1) 
    # AD test with completely specified parameters

    Anderson-Darling test of goodness-of-fit
    Null hypothesis: Normal distribution
    with parameters mean = 0, sd = 1
    Parameters assumed to be fixed

data:  testsamp
An = 1.6668, p-value = 0.1413
 ad.test(testsamp, "pnorm", mean=mean(testsamp), sd=sd(testsamp), 
         estimated = FALSE) 
# estimated parameters are considered to be true parameters

    Anderson-Darling test of goodness-of-fit
    Null hypothesis: Normal distribution
    with parameters mean = -0.17105534143913, sd = 1.04396357351905
    Parameters assumed to be fixed

data:  testsamp
An = 0.34919, p-value = 0.8969
 ad.test(testsamp, "pnorm", mean=mean(testsamp), sd=sd(testsamp), 
         estimated = TRUE) 
# AD test when parameters are estimated from data

    Anderson-Darling test of goodness-of-fit
    Braun's adjustment using 10 groups
    Null hypothesis: Normal distribution
    with parameters mean = -0.17105534143913, sd = 1.04396357351905
    Parameters assumed to have been estimated from data

data:  testsamp
Anmax = 1.7639, p-value = 0.7379
```

when the parameters are estimated from the data, and treated as a true parameter, the resulting AD statistic will always be smaller compared to the case where true parameters are specified.

However, with Braun's method, I think `Anmax` denotes the largest AD test statistic among all of the groups.

Can someone please shed some light on how this method works, and is it a reliable method for goodness of fit tests with skewed distribution?

Comment: I wouldn't use any test for this. I would use a quantile plot against the distribution you want to use, then I'd use my judgment to see if it was close enough.

Comment: Thank you. I use Q-Q and P-P plots, but I want to know how this method works and if it improves the original procedure.